# Passing arguments to jQuery event handler while creating an object

Tags: jquery, events

I'm creating an object dynamically and binding `onclick` event to it:

```
jQuery('<a/>', {
    click: function() { foo(arg1, arg2) },
    ...
})
```

Everything is working fine. The question is if it can be simplified so I don't need `funciton()` wrapper for calling `foo` function with arguments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass additional arguments to jQuery event handlers, jQuery passes the event object as the one argument to event handlers.

In jQuery 1.7 and up, the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function allows you to extend the event object by passing an object containing the data you want to use inside your handler. You can access the data on the `event.data` object

```
function foo(event) {
    event.data.arg1;
    event.data.arg2;    
}

jQuery('<a/>').on('click', {arg1: val1, arg2: val2}, foo)
```

Comment: the thing is i want my event handler to be a separate function so it can be utilised all over again.

Comment: Updated to show how you could use a reference to `foo`. You'll still need to construct the data object each time though you want to call foo, though.

Answer (score 2):

The extra closure provided by the anonymous function is a necessary step — unless you can be certain of ECMAscript 5 support (IE8 and below don't), in which case you can use the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
jQuery('<a/>', {
    click: foo.bind(this, arg1, arg2)
})
```

You can still use this method in IE8 and below if you're willing to include the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) micro-library, [which contains a shim for `bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
jQuery('<a/>', {
    click: _.bind(foo, this, arg1, arg2)
})
```

If you can't do either of these, then you're out of luck!

Comment: nice but ie limitation is uncool. anyways, thank you for revealing this approach.

Comment: @Tim it turns out Underscore will do this. Amending my answer…